# Is there any way to clear nodeJs command prompt?

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to clear out the Nodejs command prompt, if you want all previous information to disappear (start afresh without having to restart Nodejs command prompt)? My tutorial says to type in clr into it, but nothing happens when I do so.

Comment: Ctrl+L clears the command prompt screen when using node in Windows.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try

```
cls
```

or

```
process.stdout.write('\033c')
```

Vince.

Comment: `cls` is not working..

Comment: Seriously? What were they thinking? `process.stdout.write('\033c')
` is what I have to type everytime I want to clear the screen?

Comment: @SamuraiJack you can also call console.clear() or press CTRL+L on windows.